# What kind of DLL should I use (or .lib, or class)

Tags: c++, events, dll, callback

So I am new to .net and c++ and am in need of a "library" of functions that can be called and also **events** that are raised in the main application that is using the library.

I have a C++ library (.lib) that I want to add another layer (wrapper) on top of it and only expose a few functions and events for the main application.  I don't know which app technology to use : C#, VB.net, or CLR Winform (Dont know if that is the right name).

What am I looking to do?  What should I be searching for on Google?

I imagine I should be looking to make a DLL (but what kind?  I have seen C, C++, and .net C++)

Do I expose a C++ class?  But how do I raise events?  Virtual Functions I believe right?

Do I create some kind of object that the application references to have events/functions?

As you can see I am new to this technology and a newb in this area.

Thank you

Comment: Let me try to understand: You have a library that is written in C++, and you have an application that is not written in C++. You want to write a wrapper around this library so that your application can use the C++ library? If I've got that right, the biggest missing piece of information is: what language is your application written in?

Comment: I don't think he yet knows what the app will be written in: 'I don't know which app technology to use : C#, VB.net, or CLR Winform (Dont know if that is the right name).' Regardless though, he should wrap his unmanaged c/c++ DLL with a managed c++ DLL, which can then make it available to all of the .net languages.

Comment: I have a C++ library that is written.  I can write the wrapper in any language and I could write the application in any language.  Both are not written at this point.  I would imagine a GUI would be best made in C#/VB.net but then can I use a C++ class from a DLL in say VB.net or C#?

Comment: DeusAduro - Do I create a class in the managed DLL with functions  that can be called and virtual functions for the events/callbacks?  Can I then can I use that class in say C# or vb.net?

Comment: @Special K, essentially yes, although I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'virtual' functions for callbacks. .NET (c#, vb.net, c++/cli) has a nice implementation of callback functionality through 'delegates', I suggest reading about that for handling your callback/event wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

So given that you have already written a c/c++ DLL, and now want to write a GUI which uses it, here are my suggestions:

1. Write the GUI in the .net framework, namely: managed c++, c# or VB.net (I personally prefer c#).
2. To get the DLL functionality over to the .net app, you have a few options: use the [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx), or use managed c++ wrappers.

On item #2, my personal suggestion, assuming your DLL has more than a few functions, is to write a managed c++ DLL. Here is a fairly basic, but good [tutorial](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/03/29/mcpp_part3.html), it essentially comes down to compiling the DLL as managed code, and writing a wrapper class/es to allow other .net apps access to the unmanaged functions/classes.

Answer (score 0):

Woah :)

> ..CLR Winform..

You mean C++/CLI ?

Well .. It all depends on which language you wan't to use your wrapper with. A .dll can be many different things, implementation-wise, but they all have something in common: They got data which you can use from other applications. That data being methods, classes, public integers, whatever :)

If you want to use your facade in C++, then write the .dll in C++. If you want to use it from .Net, write it in any .Net language you want, using P/Invoke, or use C++/CLI - But beware of the hundreds of pitfalls there is when doing stuff cross-language. .Net uses a garbage collector, C++ doesn't (by default :) You could ofc use something like Boost pointers or the likes to get a "GC-feeling".). You don't mention which IDE you're planning to use or which O/S you're targetting. A .dll in windows is different than one in Linux for example.

Bottom-line: It depends on your target language, O/S and for easiness of writing the facade, the IDE :)

Good luck with it.

Visual studio: [C++ dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12.aspx), [.Net dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973807.aspx), [native C++ to .Net wrapper using C++/CLI](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/02/16/net-to-c-bridge.aspx)

Comment: Sorry this will be a windows based application developed in VS2008.

I believe what I am hearing is that I could make a managed C++ DLL and use the exposed class I create to call functions and also use virtual functions as the callback/event handlers?  Is that a fair statement?

Comment: Yup, that's correct.. Though I don't know why you want virtual functions, as they are only good for inheritance. Using a managed C++ dll as a facade, you can do everything you can do in other .Net languages (using System.Object-derived types, events, delegates, and all the other goodies :) ). - But beware of the memory leaks and the major differences between your .Net environment in managed C++ and the native C++ dll. You need to make sure your release your native resource manually, and create your managed resources in the .Net way, using the garbage collector.